# OfficeJS Word add-in support for Office.StartupBehavior.load

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am developing a word add-in which should be loaded on document open and it should support both desktop and web apps.

When I am trying to use

```
Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load)
```

for office word on the web then getting RichApi error.

```
RichApi.Error: InvalidRequest
at new n (word-web-16.00.js:25:309056)
at i.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (word-web-16.00.js:25:373222)
at word-web-16.00.js:25:371285
```

When are we going get 'Office.StartupBehavior.load' support for office word on the web ?

Comment: This should be supported for Word on the web now. I suggest that you create an issue at the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.